# Providing a timeout value when using @Async for a method using Spring 3.0

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous

I looked through the documentation but couldn't find if there is a way to specify a timeout for async operations spawned when using @Async annotated methods using Spring 3.0.

Is there a way to do that? I think this is pretty essential whenever making triggering an async computation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Timeouts are not provided by the `@Async` annotation, since the timeout should be decided by the caller of the function, not the function itself.

I'm assuming you're referring to the timeout on an `@Async`-annotated method which returns a result. [Such methods should return an instance of `Future`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async), and the `get()` method on `Future` is used to specify the timeout.

e.g.

```
@Async
public Future<String> doSomething() {
   return new AsyncResult<String>("test");
}
```

and then

```
Future<String> futureResult = obj.doSomething();  // spring makes this an async call
String result = futureResult.get(1, TimeUnit.SECOND);
```

Comment: but this method don't cancel the worker thread. Do you have any idea to cancel this thread?

Comment: @pablobaldez call `future.cancel(true);` if you get the timeoutException

Comment: cancel does NOTHING if you are using CompletableFuture https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html

Answer (score -2):

In [@Async source code](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/spring-context/3.0.4.RELEASE/spring-context-3.0.4.RELEASE-sources.jar!/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Async.java?format=ok) is no option for configuration.