# java spring async future block on timely manner

Tags: java, spring, asynchronous, blocking

e.g. I looking to find a way to execute `@Async` method not absolutely asynchronously.
For example I want to invoke `@Async`task that will block my process for a up to a maximum defined time if task still haven't completed.

```
@Async
public Future<ModelObject> doSomething() {
   //here we will block for a max allowed time if task still haven't been completed
}
```

So such code will be semi asynchronous but the blocking time can be controlled by developer.

P.S : of course I can achieve this by simply blocking calling thread for a limited time. but I look to achieve that within spring layer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Providing a timeout value when using @Async for a method using Spring 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785197/providing-a-timeout-value-when-using-async-for-a-method-using-spring-3-0)

Comment: no. this isn't a duplicate as the question there is how to limit the time of the whole async task execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no, there is no way to configure Spring to do this.

The `@Async` annotation is handled by the `AsyncExecutionInterceptor` which delegates the work to a `AsyncTaskExecutor`.  You could, in theory, write your own implementation of the `AsyncTaskExecutor` but even then there would be no way to use the `@Async` annotation to pass the desired wait time to your executor.  Even then, it's not clear to me what the caller's interface would look like since they'd still be getting a `Future` object back.  You would probably also need to subclass the `Future` object as well.  Basically, by the time you are finished, you will have written the entire feature again more or less from scratch.

You could always wrap the returned `Future` object in your own `WaitingFuture` proxy which provides an alternate get implementation although even then you'd have no way of specifying the wait value on the callee side:

```
WaitingFuture<ModelObject> future = new WaitingFuture<ModelObject>(service.doSomething());
ModelObject result = future.get(3000); //Instead of throwing a timeout, this impl could just return null if 3 seconds pass with no answer
if(result == null) {
    //Path A
} else {
    //Path B
}
```

Or if you don't want to write your own class then just catch the `TimeoutException`.

```
Future<ModelObject> future = doSomething();
try {
    ModelObject result = future.get(3000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    //Path B
} catch (TimeoutException ex) {
    //Path A
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an @Async method that returns a Future:

```
       Future<String> futureString = asyncTimeout(10000);
       futureString.get(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

       @Async
       public Future<String> asyncTimeout(long mills) throws InterruptedException {

               return new AsyncResult<String>(
                    sleepAndWake(mills)
               );
       }

        public String sleepAndWake(long mills) throws InterruptedException{
            Thread.sleep(mills);
            return "wake";
        }
```