# spring async timeout not working

Tags: spring, asynchronous

I've added the following to my Spring config.  I'm assuming the default-timeout value is in seconds, so I set it for three minutes.  I set up an async task to sleep the current Thread for five minutes.  I trigger the async task and it runs to completion, without an Exception or interrupt.  What am I doing wrong?

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:async-support default-timeout="180"/>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Following is the async method I'm calling:

```
@Async
    public void generateIDOIncentiveFiles(String sessionId, String userId) throws Exception
    {
        final long SLEEP_TIME_MILLS = 5 * 60 * 1000;

        try
        {
            // Get the job entry from the JOBS table
            Job job = jobsDao.getJob(RequestHelper.JOB_IDO_INCENTIVES);

            // Check to see if the job is enabled.
            if ( job.isEnabled() == false )
                throw new Exception ( "Job is not enabled" );

            // Check to see if the job is already running.

            if ( job.isRunning() )
                throw new Exception ( "Job is running" );

            // Start the timer
            StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
            sw.start();

            // Capture the date/time when the job was started
            Date jobStartDate = new Date();

            LOG.debug("Starting IDO Incentives Extract process..." );

            String jobCurrentStatus = "running";
            String jobLastRunMsg = "Job started";
            Date jobLastRunDate = new Date();

            jobsDao.updateJobStarted(userId, RequestHelper.JOB_IDO_INCENTIVES, jobLastRunDate, jobLastRunMsg, jobCurrentStatus);

            LOG.debug("Sleeping for five minutes..." );

            Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME_MILLS);

            LOG.debug("Back from sleep." );

            jobCurrentStatus = "idle";

            // Capture the date/time when the job ended
            sw.stop();
            double elapsedTime = sw.getTotalTimeSeconds();
            int elapsedTimeMinutes = (int) (elapsedTime / 60);
            Date jobEndDate = new Date();

            jobsDao.updateJobComplete(RequestHelper.JOB_IDO_INCENTIVES, "", "idle");

            // Add entry to JOB_HISTORY table

            LOG.debug("Updating job history..." );

            JobHistory jobHistory = new JobHistory();

            jobHistory.setFile_name("file name");
            jobHistory.setFile_path("file path");
            jobHistory.setElapsed_time(elapsedTimeMinutes);
            jobHistory.setEnd_date(jobEndDate);
            jobHistory.setJob_name(RequestHelper.JOB_IDO_INCENTIVES);
            jobHistory.setStart_date(jobStartDate);
            jobHistory.setStatus("Success");
            jobHistory.setUserid(userId);

            jobHistoryDao.insertJobHistory(jobHistory);

            LOG.debug("Job complete" );

        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
          e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us how you use the async task. `<mvc:async-support>` is for async request handling.

Comment: I've added the method I'm calling asynchronously.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it's as I thought. The

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:async-support default-timeout="180"/>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

`async-support` here has nothing to do with `@Async`. It has to do with [Servlet 3 asynchronous request handling.](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-async)

There is no way to provide a timeout value for the `@Async` method. [Have a look at this answer for how to actually do it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785197/providing-a-timeout-value-when-using-async-for-a-method-using-spring-3-0)

Comment: I tried using the Future object's get() method, and was able to get a TimeoutException to be thrown.  However, the Async method still kept running.  So, I guess Async methods can just keep running forever?  There's no way to stop a runaway Async process other than killing the JVM?

Comment: @MichaelSobczak Are you sure it was still running? The `ExecutorService` should return the `Thread` to its pool if an `Exception` is thrown.