# Method with Spring @Async annotation not executed

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I use spring @Async annotation to execute certain tasks.  At some point (maybe because the pool-size was reached) I see in the debugger that the method with @Async is called but the break point in the method is not reached.  I do not know it it will be called when another @Async method is finished or it is skipped forever.

I would like to know if it is possible to trigger an exception when there are not free @Async to execute it.

In addition, how can I know how many @Async are currently used at any given time

Thanks
Avi

Answer (score 1):

> At some point (maybe because the pool-size was reached) I see in the debugger that the method with @Async is called but the break point in the method is not reached.

Are you sure that the code fragment if not blocked by some conditional? Without a valid code sample, one can only speculate at this point.

> I would like to know if it is possible to trigger an exception when there are not free @Async to execute it.

A TimeoutException is usually thrown in this case. You can modify the time out value by adding the following to your Spring config XML.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven>
  <mvc:async-support default-timeout="180"/>
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Alternatively have a look at this answer:  [Providing a timeout value when using @Async for a method using Spring 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785197/providing-a-timeout-value-when-using-async-for-a-method-using-spring-3-0)

> In addition, how can I know how many @Async are currently used at any given time

Usually when you activate logging using e.g. sl4j inside the code executed inside an @Async method, you'll see the following output:

```
2017-03-10 10:27:41,910 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] DEBUG
2017-03-10 10:27:43,282 [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] DEBUG
```

Hope that this helps!