# Spring Test Annotation @Timed(milli = 1000) not working on regular java method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-scheduled

I am trying to use spring Test annotation @Timed on a regular java method to come out of the method after a certain period mentioned as a parameter. But It is not working. 
Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: You mentioned it yourself it is a TEST annotation... So no it won't work in a regular java application, nor should you have test dependencies in your regular code.

Comment: Why do you want this? Is this asynchronous code? If so, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3785197/providing-a-timeout-value-when-using-async-for-a-method-using-spring-3-0